# How can i find the number of pages in Word Document and number of slides in PPT using PHP

Tags: php, phpword

Is there any way or any API by which i can find the number of pages in word document or number of slides in a power point presentation using PHP?

any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I did check it, but i am trying the word library mentioned there, but how do i find the number of slides in PPT?

Comment: Well a library for MS Word isn't going to tell you the number of slides in an MS PowerPoint file (have you looked at PHPPowerPoint?); and you tag PHPExcel but no mention of MS Excel (or any other spreadsheet file)

Comment: Hi Mark Baker, i tagged PHPExcel because i also want to find number of slides from a ppt programatically

Comment: PHPExcel doesn't have any idea how to read a ppt file, so it's not much use to you: Excel !== Powerpoint

Comment: ok thanks Mark for the correction