# get word document count and number of slides count in PPT

Tags: java, php, com, apache-poi

Is it possible to get the number of pages in word document or number of slides in a ppt?

I have done a lot of research on it and I am desperately looking for  solution.  I saw that it is very difficult to get it done in PHP on linux server.

I would be ok with Java also, but is it possible. I checked the apache POI library, but would it work for both `ppt`, `pptx`, `doc` and `docx`?

I am rigorously searching for some solution but I am unable to get one. Any help would be really really appreciated.

Comment: Try to use `Apache poi`, a java library.

Comment: Would that work for ppt, pptx, doc and docx?

Comment: @opensource-ios why not try it?

Comment: Hi matt, i am not very aware of Java, I know PHP, for me to try it would take a lot of time, i would love to try myslef, but if i could be sure it works, it would be great.

Comment: I believe ms openxml library is broadly mono compliant, and works well with these document formats. Would involve installing mono, writing some c# and calling the resulting executable from php. There is probably a simpler solution

Comment: user574632,but my environment is LINUX server

Comment: @opensource-ios yes, hence why MONO compliance is key. MONO lets you run .net on linux and other platforms http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Comment: So how is this any different to your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984443/access-word-document-properties-and-power-point-document-properties-using-php-co) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834697/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-pages-in-word-document-and-number-of-slides-in-ppt) on the same subject?

Comment: @ Mark Baker, previously It was restricted to PHP, now i am looking for any kind of solution which i can integrate.

Comment: Thanks user574632, i will check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get meta data properties of `doc`, `docx`, `ppt` and `pptx` like number of pages, number of slides I followed the following process and it worked liked a charm. Hope it helps someone:

1. Download and configure [`Apache Tika`](https://tika.apache.org/)
2. Once its done you could try executing the following commands, to get all the meta data about your file:

```
java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar -m test.docx
java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar -m test.doc
java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar -m test.pptx
java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar -m test.ppt
```

Once tested you can execute these commands in a PHP script. Thanks.